# unable to add data to ag-grid dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to populate the rows of ag-grid dynamically.The grid must be shown only when i send a file for validation and there are some errors. Below is my code:

```
columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'S.No.', field : 'SNo'},
    {headerName: 'Error Description', field: 'Error_Description'},
    {headerName: 'Suggestion', field: 'Suggestion'}
  ];

rowData = [
    // {SNo :1, Error_Description:"Error 1", Suggestion: 'Suggestion 1'},
    // {SNo :2, Error_Description:"Error 2", Suggestion: 'Suggestion 2'},
    // {SNo :3, Error_Description:"Error 3", Suggestion: 'Suggestion 3'},
    // {SNo :4, Error_Description:"Error 4", Suggestion: 'Suggestion 4'}
  ];
```

**index.html**

```
<ag-grid-angular [hidden]="isValid" class="ag-theme-balham" style="width: fit-content" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
        <!-- Show table -->
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

**dynamic population of grid rows**

```
for(var i=0;i<this.errorMsgs.length;i++){
        let errorObj={};
        errorObj["SNo"]=i+1;
        errorObj["Error_Description"]=this.errorMsgs[i];
        errorObj["Suggestion"]="Put Some Suggestion"
        this.rowData.push(errorObj);
      }
```

When i use the hardcoded values(commented values) i get the expected output. However, when i try to populate the grid dynamically the data is not displayed. The data is pushed into the rowData but for some reason, it doesn't show in the table. What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance and apology if this is a silly question as this is the first time i am working with ag-grid

Comment: When is your for loop (the one that populates the `rowData` variable) running? And what is the content of `this.errorMsgs`?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis the loop runs upon a function call. And ```errorMsgs``` is a String array

Comment: Ideally it should run in the `ngOnInit()` of your component. You should read about the angular lifecycle: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I am validating a file. And if there are any validation errors, only then i need to update the ag-grid with the description of error

Comment: Try replacing your line: `this.rowData.push(errorObj);` with `this.rowData = [...this.rowData, errorObj];`

Comment: As @IraklisGkougkousis pointed out, Angular's change detection may be the one screwing with you

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis your solution worked! What is the meaning of ```[...this.rowData,errorObj]```?

Comment: @SamarthSaxena See my answer below

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis can you please also tell me if i want to clear all the row values, how do i do it?

Comment: @SamarthSaxena `this.rowData = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably Angular's change detection messing with you. When you `push` to an array, the contents of the array change, but Angular might not pick that up, since it usually depends on changes to *reference* instead of *value*.

Replace:

```js
this.rowData.push(errorObj);
```

with

```js
this.rowData = [...this.rowData, errorObj];
```

This will "add" the new `errorObj` to the `rowData` by essentially creating a new array and reassigning the *reference* of the new array to `rowData`. It relies on the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). I also recommend reading more about [Angular Change Detection](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/).

Answer (score 0):

Use setRowData() of gridApi in order to add values to grid. 
It's better to use this inside onGridReady method.